# Redirect class variable to class function

Tags: python, oop

Let's take a simple class as an example:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1
        self.z = 1
```

What I would like is to give this class a variable called `sum` such that when I do

```
v = Vector()
v.sum
```

I am given the sum `x+y+z` (in this case 3). Of course I can easily just make a class method that does this, but then I would have to write `v.sum()` instead of `v.sum`. Is there any way to hide the fact that the class actually calls a function when asking for a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note, "class variable" and "class function" are _highly_ misleading names, because almost anyone will take them as synonyms for "class attribute" and "class method", not "instance attribute" and "instance method".

Comment: Vector shouldn't have a `sum` attribute... Why would you want to make it an attribute instead of a method?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen - it can make certain code neater and clearer, especially in maths (though I wouldn't advise overusing it).  `numpy` does this for the `matrix` class (transpose is `.T`, inverse is `.I` etc)

Comment: @sapi Yeah I understand, but I don't think it's still a good thing to do. It's the same as naming variables `fp, kn, hv` or other abbrevations. Might make it much neater, but you shouldn't do it just to make something look nicer.

Comment: Calling my class Vector was probably a bad idea. I agree, a sum doesn't make much sense. It was just to come up with a quick example.

Reason I wanted it: sometimes I think that a function wouldn't be natural. For instance, say that we an instance `x` of a colour class. Maybe I would like that people can obtain both RGB values and  CMYK values. I don't want to store the information twice, but at the same time I want people to access them on an equal footing, e.g. `x.B` and `x.C`. This would be a use-case. At least in my head.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class Vector(object): # subclass object for new style class

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1
        self.z = 1

    @property
    def sum(self):
        return self.x + self.y + self.z
```

---

```
>>> v = Vector()
>>> v.sum
3
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property